# Login page cant redirect to another page if user has logged in

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code i have used to login. If i give the wrong username and password i wont stay on the log in page and the index.php will automatically refresh?

```
 <?php
    // When clicked on button Login
    if(isset($_POST['inloggen'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password'])) {

        } //Controls the statement if username and password are empty get an error else get into the database and get the login details.
        else {
            $username = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
            $password = $_POST['wachtwoord'];

            set_include_path (include "/database/DBconnectie.php");

            //de tabel selecteren van de database
            $sql = "SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM klanten, medewerkers WHERE gebruikersnaam='$username' AND wachtwoord='$password'";
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if ($query) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                $dbgebruiker = $row['gebruikersnaam'];
                $dbwachtwoord = $row['wachtwoord'];
                $gebruikercheck = $row['med_gebruikersnaam'];
            }
            if ($username == $dbgebruiker && $password == $dbwachtwoord) {
                $_SESSION['gebruikersnaam'] = $dbgebruiker;
                $_SESSION['wachtwoord'] = $dbwachtwoord;
                $_SESSION['med_gebruikersnaam'] = $gebruikercheck;


                //controleren of de klant een medewerker is
                if ($gebruikercheck == $username) {
                    header('Location: medewerkers/index.php');
                } //als het geen medewerker is dan log je in als klant
                else {
                    header('Location: kopers/index.php');
                }
            } else {
                $melding = "Onjuiste gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord";

            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This is the tabel i've used to log on. It is just a simple log in pup window.

```
<!-- Gebruikersnaam & Wachtwoord Login form -->
                    <div class="user_login">
                        <form method="POST">
                            <label style="margin-top:-4%;">Gebruikersnaam:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam"/>
                            <br/>
                            <label style="margin-top:-6%;">Wachtwoord:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="wachtwoord"/>
                            <a href="#" class="forgot_password" style=" margin-top:-0.3%;">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="action_btns" style="margin-top:-8%; margin-bottom:9%;">
                                <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i
                                            class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>Terug</a></div>
                                <div class="one_half last"><button type="submit" class="btn btn_red" name="inloggen">Inloggen</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <?=$melding;?>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The medewerkers/index.php is the page where you are going to redirected to when you aer logged on as a collaborator. I have to log in via my homepage index.php

Comment: Note that you aren't escaping user input and are there open to SQL-injection. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: In you form try giving the field 'inloggen' a value. LIke:
`<button type="submit" class="btn btn_red" name="inloggen" value="example">Inloggen</button>`
Currently the button doesn't have a "value" attribute set, while the form will  send the name/value pairs to the php code. And since the button doesn't have a value the line `if(isset($_POST['inloggen']))`will always return false (as the field doesn't have a value). See: 
[w3 standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html)

Also: move you 'html form' to your question as it isn't a answer but part of your question

Comment: Hmm, thank you Nathan. Probably is that a fault that i've made, but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$sql = "SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM klanten, medewerkers WHERE gebruikersnaam='$username' AND wachtwoord='$password'";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT med_gebruikersnaam,gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM klanten, medewerkers WHERE gebruikersnaam='$username' AND wachtwoord='$password'";
```

Because you are not selecting `med_gebruikersnaam`, so:

```
$gebruikercheck = $row['med_gebruikersnaam']; //will always be unidentified.
```

And if `$gebruikercheck` is unidentified, then this:

```
if ($gebruikercheck == $username) //will return false always.
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. When i click on the Log in button the website is going to refresh hisself without doing anything?